# Why do I keep getting a captcha?

Tags: support

Any time I post a question or answer, I have to enter a captcha. I don't get this on other stack exchange sites.

Comment: No repo for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a bug with iPad / iPhone (anywhere we disable the WMD editor) that would cause this. Now fixed.

If that's not your issue, then I suspect you have javascript disabled and possibly other issues with your browser.

Comment: Now that I think of it, most of my use of this site was from my Ipad. I'll keep an eye out for it, but I would think it is same to assume that was the issue and it is fixed. Thanks.   [edit: I just tested this from my Ipad, and I didn't get the captcha.]

Answer (score 2):

I've been getting it periodically.  I thought it was happening when I posted too fast or too much in a given time period.

Comment: that was my first thought as well, but I have to no matter how long it has been since my last one